Wifi EV Charger Load Balancer and network compatibility
I have a Defa Power EV Charger, and a Defa Wireless Balancer for electrical load balancing. This all used to work fine on my Netgear R7000 DD-WRT wireless network.
Now I have recently purchased Asus ZenWifi XT8 Mesh routers and setup a 3 node mesh. The Defa Power and Defa Balancer are both connected to the wireless SSID, but the setup app will not register or "see" the Balancer to connect to. If I setup a different network SSID with my old R7000 it will see the Balancer when connected in the setup app just fine.
The requirements stated on the website are:
"
DEFA Balancer supports Wi-Fi (2.4 or 5GHz) and ethernet connections. DEFA Balancer needs to be connected to the same network as the charging station. Network must support IPv4 multicast between DEFA Balancer and DEFA Power(s)."
I have tried enabling multicast routing in the ASUS Router Admin:

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Should my Asus ZenWifi XT8 Mesh support multicast ipv4 and should this be working? Are there any other reasons why this might not work?
After speaking to Defa customer support their suggestion was to separate the 2G and 5G bands to different SSIDs. I did this and connected both devices to the 2G band and it did work.
The old Netgear R7000 was not a mesh wifi and did not have smart connection, it also had separate 2G and 5G SSIDs.
As a response to the comment, when smart connect was previously enabled and there was only one SSID for both bands, I did verify that both devices were connected to the network and each had a valid network address. I did not verify (or bind) each device, the Power and Balancer, to the same node, in fact they are not in range of the same node. And I did not verify if they were connected via different bands. With smart connect enabled it was possible they were changing bands.
The current setup has the main node connected to another with wired connection (dedicated LAN backhaul). Another node is connected wirelessly with dedicated backhaul set to 5G-2.


Check to make sure there is no "station" or "client" separation enabled.

A potential solution was to separate the wifi bands to separate 2g and 5g networks and connect the devices to the same bands, then it did recognise it. Unfortunately this requires the entire smart connect of the wifi mesh system to be disabled.

So the mesh is applying separation between the bands, even id they have the same SSID? That's just poor and is going to break SO many IoT devices that use things like mDNS/Avahi for discovery. If possible keep the 2 bands joined and just add a second SSID on 2.4 only for just these to bits of kit

That seems really weird. Did you confirm that both devices were connected to the APs when they couldn't see each other? Were they connected to the same one? What backhaul are you using between the APs (wired or wireless)? If wired, are 2 of the devices really set up as APs rather than routers (and/or is the backhaul connected to a LAN rather than WAN port)?

Some devices that only work on 2G will not work on a dual SSID. Its just the way their code is written.
You dont have to split the network totally. If you have a decent router, you can set up multiple networks, you can set up

One with just 2G
Another with both 2G and 5G.


Ok, so after a lot of trial and error this is how I managed to connect a Defa Power and Defa Balancer to an Asus Zenwifi AiMesh network using XT8 router and nodes. Either,
A) Separate the Tri-band network into two separate 2G and 5G networks and connect the devices to the same band. This is a little annoying if you like the single SSID for all devices, or
B) Keep your main network in Tri-Band-Mode and create a guest network (I used 2G) and connect the devices to this network. In order to get this to work I needed to use two settings:
i) Enable Intranet Access on the Guest Network:

ii) Require Protected Management Frames on the Main Network
:
Even with protected management frames and the devices connected to the same channel on the main network I could not get these devices to communicate.
Ultimately I don't know if this was all due to weak signals, or lagging feedback in the apps and not reporting the devices precisely in realtime.
But what I can say for certain is that this is definitely less fun that having a more powerful single router directly connecting the devices!
